# tables in html not aligning side by side

Tags: html, css, css-float

i am trying to align 3 tables next to each other but they so not follow what i command. i tried adding`style="float:left;"` to the table tags but it not works

here is screenshot from first table [image: click to view]

here is my code

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body,
ol,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
th,
td,
dl,
dd,
form,
fieldset,
legend,
input,
textarea,
select {
  background-color: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#86090F 0%, #EA3C22 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.clear {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.fl {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.fr {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 150%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 85px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #404040;
  background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
}
b .img {
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  height: 85px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.content1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content1 h3 {
  font: blone 14px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.content1 table {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
}
.content1 table td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 25px;
  font: 20px"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 95%;
}
.content1 table tr {
  border: none;
}
.box {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.content2 {
  width: 490px;
  float: left;
}
.content2 h3 {
  font: blone 14px Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.lyb_box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
}
.lyb_box_nr {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.lyb_box_nr p {
  font: normal 14px Arial;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.lyb_box_nr input {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.lyb_box_nr select {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
article {
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid #404040;
  float: right;
}
.search {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}
.content3 {
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  margin-top: 31px;
}
.content4 {
  float: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  margin-left: 700px;
}
#nav {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 2.8;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -50px auto;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #adadad;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #adadad;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#nav a:active {
  color: green;
  background-color: white;
}
#nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  color: red;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #86090F;
  margin: 0 px auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
}
#footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: withe;
}
#footer a,
#footer a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#legal {
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 120px 20px 24px;
}
li.first {
  padding-left: 45%;
}
li:not(#flag) {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#k {
  padding-left: 40%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 0 px solid #404040;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.blink_text {
  text-align: center;
  animation: 1s blinker linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blinker linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blinker linear infinite;
  color: red;
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
.normalmessage {
  text-align: center;
}
/*!
Pure v0.6.0
Copyright 2014 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the BSD License.
https://github.com/yahoo/pure/blob/master/LICENSE.md
*/

.pure-table {
  /* Remove spacing between table cells (from Normalize.css) */
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  empty-cells: show;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
.pure-table caption {
  color: #000;
  font: italic 85%/1 arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.pure-table td,
.pure-table th {
  border-left: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  /*  inner column border */
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  /*to make ths where the title is really long work*/
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  /* cell padding */
}
/* Consider removing this next declaration block, as it causes problems when
there's a rowspan on the first cell. Case added to the tests. issue#432 */

.pure-table td:first-child,
.pure-table th:first-child {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.pure-table thead {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
/*
striping:
   even - #fff (white)
   odd  - #f2f2f2 (light gray)
*/

.pure-table td {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.pure-table-odd td {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/* nth-child selector for modern browsers */

.pure-table-striped tr:nth-child(2n-1) td {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/* BORDERED TABLES */

.pure-table-bordered td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
}
.pure-table-bordered tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
/* HORIZONTAL BORDERED TABLES */

.pure-table-horizontal td,
.pure-table-horizontal th {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
.pure-table-horizontal tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<header>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="nav">
    <p id="time"></p>
  </div>
</header>

<head>
  <title>LT</title>
  <script>
    var date = new Date();
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(1);
    }, (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000)
  </script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
  <script src="sprintf.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="2.0.0-crypto-sha1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="2.0.0-hmac-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>




  <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered" id="depart" style="float:left;">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th width="38%">Bus Route</th>
        <th width="15%">Time</th>
        <th width="50%">Remaining</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div style="clear: both"></div>
  <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered" style="float:left;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Honda</td>
        <td>Accord</td>
        <td>2009</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Camry</td>
        <td>2012</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Hyundai</td>
        <td>Elantra</td>
        <td>2010</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



  <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered" style="float:left;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Honda</td>
        <td>Accord</td>
        <td>2009</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Camry</td>
        <td>2012</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Hyundai</td>
        <td>Elantra</td>
        <td>2010</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <footer id="footer">





  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

this is a uni project in first table i will be displaying information about departing buses, in second about trains and in third about trams.
so all three tables should be displayed next to each other. 
Also this page will be static which means users will not interact with this page. This page is to display departing transport to users on a screen which will be placed in uni. please help.

Comment: I see <div style="clear: both"></div> after the first table. That one will push the next table down to a new line.

Comment: Looking at your code snippet above, your tables do align next to each other and that's because of the float, the first table doesn't because there is there is an empty tag below it that's clearing the float; `<div style="clear: both"></div>`. If you expand your snippet to fullscreen and remove this float you'll have them line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<div style="clear: both"></div>` from your html.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need of using `float:left;` u should use `display:inline;` 
secondly in ur html code u have cleared the floating after the first table `<div style="clear: both"></div>`

just do these 2 changes and your code will work